# What is the best way of moving my data from one container to newer container of cosmos db

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am going to move my documents in one of my container to my newer container in same database. the newer container will be created with a partition key. I would like to know what will be best way to do this action using Azure Services and what should I take into account while starting my migration. The documents are more than millions in number. Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-migrationchoices

Comment: followed this and I started with DMT which document says the preferred one but I get error as ""Errors":["The collection cannot be accessed with this SDK version as it was created with newer SDK version."]}". I simply created the target collection from the UI

Comment: I would recommend posting a separate question for this.